# certificate verify failed- in run docker on python

Tags: python

I want to run a python file in Docker but I keep getting an error.

This is the Python file:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app=FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello":"World"}
```

this is the dockerfile:

```
FROM python

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN pip install --upgrade certifi

RUN pip install fastapi uvicorn[standard]

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "./MyApp.py" ]
```

I ran the command:
`docker build -t my-app .`
And I got this error:

```
#6 1.419 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)'))': /simple/certifi/
#6 2.010 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)'))': /simple/certifi/
#6 3.112 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)'))': /simple/certifi/
#6 5.205 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)'))': /simple/certifi/
#6 9.297 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)'))': /simple/certifi/
#6 9.456 Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/certifi/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/certifi/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)'))) - skipping
#6 9.461 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement certifi (from versions: none)
#6 9.461 ERROR: No matching distribution found for certifi
#6 9.545 Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)'))) - skipping
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install --upgrade certifi]: exit code: 1
```

what is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is the line I added in the dockerfile and it solved the problem:

```
RUN pip install fastapi --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host  files.pythonhosted.org
```